in_app_purchase: ^3.2.0 flutter error "You already own this item" after some buy
"Im using in_app_purchase: ^3.2.0 package for my flutter app. I have list the products and make thing good. But issue is im hitting
"
_inAppPurchase.buyConsumable( purchaseParam: purchaseParam, autoConsume: _kAutoConsume);
"issue is when im trying to buy iteam it work fine unti 9th time after it is shows Error "You already own this item" . im in debug mode. but i want to but consumable item agian and again without any count restriction. also from Order Managment when i refund last purchase then im able to again buy that product 2 time then again got same issue.
Also i dont want to put restore purchase button in my app
im try to buy consumable product in my flutter android app multiple time. "

i fixed this but addinf consumePurchase in my code like this

 Future<void> _listenToPurchaseUpdated(
      List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
    for (final PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
        showPendingUI();
      } else {
        if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
          handleError(purchaseDetails.error!);
        } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased ||
            purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
          final bool valid = await _verifyPurchase(purchaseDetails);
          if (valid) {
            unawaited(deliverProduct(purchaseDetails));
          } else {
            _handleInvalidPurchase(purchaseDetails);
            return;
          }

          if (Platform.isAndroid) {
            final InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition androidAddition =
            _inAppPurchase.getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>();
            await androidAddition.consumePurchase(purchaseDetails);
            debugPrint('Purchase consumed: ${purchaseDetails.productID}');
          }
        }
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          if (!_kAutoConsume && purchaseDetails.productID == _kConsumableId) {
            final InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition androidAddition =
            _inAppPurchase.getPlatformAddition<
                InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>();
            await androidAddition.consumePurchase(purchaseDetails);
            debugPrint('Purchase manually consumed: ${purchaseDetails.productID}');
          }
        }
        if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
          await _inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
          debugPrint('Purchase completed: ${purchaseDetails.productID}');
        }
      }
    }
  }

